# How to find the center of circle using the least square fit in python?

Tags: python, scipy, geometry

I'm trying to fit some data points in order to find the center of a circle. All of the following points are noisy data points around the circumference of the circle:

```
data = [(2.2176383052987667, 4.218574252410221),
(3.3041214516913033, 5.223500807396272),
(4.280815855023374, 6.461487709813785),
(4.946375258539319, 7.606952538212697),
(5.382428804463699, 9.045717060494576),
(5.752578028217334, 10.613667377465823),
(5.547729017414035, 11.92662513852466),
(5.260208374620305, 13.57722448066025),
(4.642126672822957, 14.88238955729078),
(3.820310290976751, 16.10605425390148),
(2.8099420132544024, 17.225880123445773),
(1.5731539516426183, 18.17052077121059),
(0.31752822350872545, 18.75261434891438),
(-1.2408437559671106, 19.119355580780265),
(-2.680901948575409, 19.15018791257732),
(-4.190406775175328, 19.001321726517297),
(-5.533990404926917, 18.64857428377178),
(-6.903383826792998, 17.730112542165955),
(-8.082883753215347, 16.928080323602334),
(-9.138397388219254, 15.84088004983959),
(-9.92610373064812, 14.380575762984085),
(-10.358670204629814, 13.018017342781242),
(-10.600053524240247, 11.387283417089911),
(-10.463673966507077, 10.107554951600699),
(-10.179820255235496, 8.429558128401448),
(-9.572153386953028, 7.1976672709797676),
(-8.641475289758178, 5.8312286526738175),
(-7.665976739804268, 4.782663065707469),
(-6.493033077746997, 3.8549965442534684),
(-5.092340806635571, 3.384419909199452),
(-3.6530364510489073, 2.992272643733981),
(-2.1522365767310796, 3.020780664301393),
(-0.6855406924835704, 3.0767643753777447),
(0.7848958776292426, 3.6196842530995332),
(2.0614188482646947, 4.32795711960546),
(3.2705467984691508, 5.295836809444288),
(4.359297538484424, 6.378324784240816),
(4.981264502955681, 7.823851404553242)]
```

I was trying to use some library like [Scipy](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Least_Squares_Circle.html#Basic-usage), but I'm having trouble using the available functions.

There is for example:

```
#  == METHOD 2 ==
from scipy      import optimize

method_2 = "leastsq"

def calc_R(xc, yc):
    """ calculate the distance of each 2D points from the center (xc, yc) """
    return sqrt((x-xc)**2 + (y-yc)**2)

def f_2(c):
    """ calculate the algebraic distance between the data points and the mean circle centered at c=(xc, yc) """
    Ri = calc_R(*c)
    return Ri - Ri.mean()

center_estimate = x_m, y_m
center_2, ier = optimize.leastsq(f_2, center_estimate)

xc_2, yc_2 = center_2
Ri_2       = calc_R(*center_2)
R_2        = Ri_2.mean()
residu_2   = sum((Ri_2 - R_2)**2)
```

But this seems to be using a single xy? Any ideas on how to plug this function to my data example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your data points seem fairly clean and I see no outliers, so many circle fitting algorithms will work.

I recommend you to start with the Coope method, which works by magically linearizing the problem:

`(X-Xc)² + (Y-Yc)² = R²` is rewritten as

`2 Xc X + 2 Yc Y + R² - Xc² - Yc² = X² + Y²`, then

`A X + B Y + C = X² + Y²`, solved by **linear** least squares.

Comment: It looks like @MadPhysicist did end up adding it. You can find the function here: https://github.com/madphysicist/scikit-guess/blob/master/src/skg/nsphere.py. Oh, and it is documented here: https://scikit-guess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/skg.nsphere.html

Answer (score 5):

As a follow up to Bas Swinckels post, I figured I'd post my code implementing the Halir and Flusser method of fitting an ellipse

https://github.com/bdhammel/least-squares-ellipse-fitting

```
pip install lsq-ellipse
```

Now make the data into a numpy array using
import numpy as np
data=np.array(data)

Using the above code you can find the center with the following method.

```
from ellipse import LsqEllipse
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statistics
from statistics import mean 

from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

lsqe = LsqEllipse()
lsqe.fit(data)
center, width, height, phi = lsqe.as_parameters()

plt.close('all')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis('equal')
ax.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], 'ro', label='test data', zorder=1)

ellipse = Ellipse(xy=center, width=2*width, height=2*height, angle=np.rad2deg(phi),
              edgecolor='b', fc='None', lw=2, label='Fit', zorder = 2)
ax.add_patch(ellipse)
print('center of fitted circle =',center, '\n','radius =', mean([width,height]),'+/- stddev=',statistics.stdev([width,height]))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Here we just take average of height and width of this ellipse as the radius of the circular fit and their standard deviation as the error. This can be modified

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I'm a fan of Coope's method, but Halir and Flusser are OK in a pinch as well :)

Answer (score 3):

I do not have any experience fitting circles, but I have worked with the more general case of fitting ellipses. Doing this in a correct way with noisy data is not trivial. For this problem, the algorithm described in [Numerically stable direct least squares fitting of ellipses](http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/WSCG98.pdf) by Halir and Flusser works pretty well. The paper includes Matlab code, which should be straightforward to translate to Numpy. Maybe you could use this algorithm to fit an ellipse and then take the average of the two axis as the radius or so. Some of the references in the paper also mention fitting circles, you might want to look those up.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but in 2019 there's a circle fitting library in python called `circle-fit`.

```
pip install circle-fit
```

you can use one of two algorithms to solve, `least_squares_circle` or `hyper_fit`.

```
import circle_fit as cf
xc,yc,r,_ = cf.least_squares_circle((data)
```

then you get `xc, yc` as the coordinate pair for the solution circle center.

Comment: Which method do you use? H&F? Coope?

Answer (score 2):

Ian Coope's algorithm (paper [here](https://ir.canterbury.ac.nz/handle/10092/11104)) linearizes the problem using a variable substitution. It's the most generally robust and fastest algorithm I've come across for circle fitting so far. I've implemented the algorithm in python in [scikit-guess](https://scikit-guess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Using the function [`skg.nsphere_fit`](https://scikit-guess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/skg.nsphere_fit.html) for a one-line solution:

```
>>> r, c = skg.nsphere_fit(data)
```

```
>>> r
8.138962707494084
>>> c
array([-2.45595128, 11.04352796])
```

Here is a plot of the result:

```
t = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000, endpoint=True)
plt.scatter(*np.array(data).T, color='r')
plt.plot(r * np.cos(t) + c[0], r * np.sin(t) + c[1])
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]